# How to merge my working Python code with Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

**ALERT: Main coding problem solved, just need this smaller question answered:**

*As for my final question: How do I make my textinput widget (or whatever this is) centered?
And to make it more precise: I want the very text I write centered inside the textinput widged, not widget centered inside bigger structure.*

*

*

So I have a little Python code (just simple calendar converter) done for learning purposes which works just fine.

```
data = input("Wpisz date w formacie DD.MM.YYYY : ")

dzien = int(data[0:2])
miesiac = int(data[3:5])
rok = int(data[6:10])

m_31 = 31
m_30 = 30
m_29 = 29
m_28 = 28

miesiace = ["Styczen", "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Maj", "Czerwiec", "Lipiec", "Sierpien", "Wrzesien", "Pazdziernik", "Listopad", "Grudzien"]
dni_tygodnia = ["Poniedzialek", "Wtorek", "Sroda", "Czwartek", "Piatek", "Sobota", "Niedziela"]
rok_zwykly = [m_31, m_28, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31]
rok_przestepny = [m_31, m_29, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31]

if  (rok%4 == 0 and rok%100 != 0):
    dzien_roku = sum(rok_przestepny[0:miesiac-1]) + dzien
elif(rok%4 == 0 and rok%100 == 0 and rok%400 == 0):
    dzien_roku = sum(rok_przestepny[0:miesiac-1]) + dzien
else:
    dzien_roku = sum(rok_zwykly[0:miesiac-1]) + dzien

dni = 0
lata = range(0, rok)
for i in lata:
    dni = dni + 365
for i in lata:
    if (i%4 == 0 and i%100 != 0):
        dni = dni + 1
    elif (i%4 ==0 and i%100 == 0 and i%400 == 0):
        dni = dni + 1
    else:
        dni = dni
dni = dni + dzien_roku
dzien_tygodnia = (dni+5)%7


lata_przestepne = 0
for i in range(0, 2012):
    if (i%4 == 0 and i%100 != 0):
        lata_przestepne = lata_przestepne +1
    elif (i%4 ==0 and i%100 == 0 and i%400 == 0):
        lata_przestepne = lata_przestepne +1
    else:
        lata_przestepne = lata_przestepne

current_long_count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
current_long_count_equivalent = 1872000 + dni - 356 - 2012*365 - lata_przestepne

if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) / 144000 >= 1:
    current_long_count[0] = current_long_count[0] + current_long_count_equivalent // 144000
else:
    current_long_count = current_long_count

if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 / 7200 >= 1:
    current_long_count[1] = current_long_count[1] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 // 7200
else:
    current_long_count = current_long_count

if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 % 7200 / 360 >= 1:
    current_long_count[2] = current_long_count[2] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 % 7200 // 360
else:
    current_long_count = current_long_count

if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 % 7200 % 360 / 20 >= 1:
    current_long_count[3] = current_long_count[3] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 % 7200 % 360 // 20
else:
    current_long_count = current_long_count

if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 % 7200 % 360 % 20 >= 1:
    current_long_count[4] = current_long_count[4] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 % 7200 % 360 % 20
else:
    current_long_count = current_long_count

print(str(dzien) + " - " + miesiace[miesiac-1] + " - " + str(rok))
print(dni_tygodnia[dzien_tygodnia -1])
print(str(dzien_roku) + " dzien w roku " + str(rok))
print("Dzien " + str(current_long_count[0]) + "." + str(current_long_count[1]) + "." + str(current_long_count[2]) + "." + str(current_long_count[3]) + "." + str(current_long_count[4]) + " Dlugiej Rachuby")
```

I also have a bit of an idea how to make a Kivy Layout based on few examples floating around the web. What I can't find anywhere though is how to merge one with another. My example layout is here (yes, I want everything in 1 file for now if possible):

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Calendar(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        ti = TextInput(font_size = 60, text = "Here I want input")
        to = Label (text = "Here I want output", font_size = 60)

        b.add_widget(ti)
        b.add_widget(to)
        return b


if __name__ == "__main__":
        Calendar().run()
```

What I want is just 2 boxes (using boxlayout or gridlayout IDC), one of which will be my program's input and the other my program's output. And as simple as it sounds I can't find any examples of how to do it (not to mention complete lack of "Zero to Hero" kivy tutorial out there in the web).

Thanks in advance for help.

P.S. My level of expertise (meaning = the lack of it) call for as simple solution as possible (even if it is not "pretty"), and as much of an explanation as possible.

Comment: have you looked at the kivy crash course tutorials? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8N_8WkALdE

Comment: Yes I did - it's probably the only reliable source out there. But the only variable "transmission" presented there is the setter() function which is of no use to me (while what I want is: Write Date > Press Enter > Get Result). Also as all of tutorials I found this one is pretty shallow (although the best in terms of unerstandability).

Comment: Without knowing how much python experience you have, it's hard to provide an answer to this. Developing with kivy will be hard if you don't know much about classes. And avoiding kivys useful 'kv lang' will make all your kivy projects twice as long as they could be with kv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use kv it saves you time: [start here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html). Look at the [basic example of button action](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/guide/designwithkv) to figure out how to start with your case, as well as [TextInput documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html)

There are [many examples](http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/examples.html) available.

You may use the `on_text_validate` event from the TextInput widget to run a function with your logics that would update the label. Here is an example that updates a label with the text input value when the user press enter:

```
# main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

def process_my_data(input_data):
    return input_data+' I was processed!'

class MainLayout(BoxLayout):

    def update_label(self):
        input_data=self.ids.my_input.text
        #~ your logics goes here
        #~ do wathever you want with input data
        output_data=process_my_data(input_data)
        #~ and then update the label with the result
        self.ids.my_output.text=output_data


class Controller(App):

    def build(self):
        my_layout = MainLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        return my_layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
        Controller().run()
```

And the kv file:

```
# controller.kv

<MainLayout>:
    TextInput:
        id: my_input
        multiline: False
        text: ''
        on_text_validate: root.update_label()
    Label:
        id: my_output
        text: ''
```

Comment: Examples You link to are the ones inside Kivy itself. I watched them all but they show only how to build a menu. None of them present a way to pass input from that menu to the actuall program written in Python. As for Kivy Documentation of official site it is (as I already said) barely usefull at best as it presents out-of-context parts of code not entire working examples as respectable tutorial should.

As for Your code solution: What should I write to pass this "input_data" to my variable "data" (date in polish) and back to Kivy. Just the usual data = input_data?

Comment: Just use a function that returns your processed data. Fixed the example

Answer (score 0):

**ALERT: Smaller sub-question at the end of the post.**

So thanks to the syntax_error I got my code working with Kivy just fine. Great thanks man, Your help was invaluable.
So for others to learn on my example as well, here is my working code.

Python part:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Calendar(BoxLayout):
    def calculation(self):
        data = self.ids.my_date.text

        dzien = int(data[0:2])
        miesiac = int(data[3:5])
        rok = int(data[6:10])

        m_31 = 31
        m_30 = 30
        m_29 = 29
        m_28 = 28

        miesiace = ["Styczen", "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Maj", "Czerwiec", "Lipiec", "Sierpien", "Wrzesien", "Pazdziernik", "Listopad", "Grudzien"]
        dni_tygodnia = ["Poniedzialek", "Wtorek", "Sroda", "Czwartek", "Piatek", "Sobota", "Niedziela"]
        rok_zwykly = [m_31, m_28, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31]
        rok_przestepny = [m_31, m_29, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_31, m_30, m_31, m_30, m_31]

        if  (rok%4 == 0 and rok%100 != 0):
            dzien_roku = sum(rok_przestepny[0:miesiac-1]) + dzien
        elif(rok%4 == 0 and rok%100 == 0 and rok%400 == 0):
            dzien_roku = sum(rok_przestepny[0:miesiac-1]) + dzien
        else:
            dzien_roku = sum(rok_zwykly[0:miesiac-1]) + dzien

        dni = 0
        lata = range(0, rok)
        for i in lata:
            dni = dni + 365
        for i in lata:
            if (i%4 == 0 and i%100 != 0):
                dni = dni + 1
            elif (i%4 ==0 and i%100 == 0 and i%400 == 0):
                dni = dni + 1
            else:
                dni = dni
        dni = dni + dzien_roku
        dzien_tygodnia = (dni+5)%7

        lata_przestepne = 0

        for i in range(0, 2012):
            if (i%4 == 0 and i%100 != 0):
                lata_przestepne = lata_przestepne +1
            elif (i%4 ==0 and i%100 == 0 and i%400 == 0):
                lata_przestepne = lata_przestepne +1
            else:
                lata_przestepne = lata_przestepne

        current_long_count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        current_long_count_equivalent = 1872000 + dni - 356 - 2012*365 - lata_przestepne

        if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) / 144000 >= 1:
            current_long_count[0] = current_long_count[0] + current_long_count_equivalent // 144000
        else:
            current_long_count = current_long_count

        if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 / 7200 >= 1:
            current_long_count[1] = current_long_count[1] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 // 7200
        else:
            current_long_count = current_long_count

        if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 % 7200 / 360 >= 1:
            current_long_count[2] = current_long_count[2] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 % 7200 // 360
        else:
            current_long_count = current_long_count

        if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 % 7200 % 360 / 20 >= 1:
            current_long_count[3] = current_long_count[3] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 % 7200 % 360 // 20
        else:
            current_long_count = current_long_count

        if abs(current_long_count_equivalent) % 144000 % 7200 % 360 % 20 >= 1:
            current_long_count[4] = current_long_count[4] + current_long_count_equivalent % 144000 % 7200 % 360 % 20
        else:
            current_long_count = current_long_count

        self.ids.my_dzien.text = str(dzien)
        self.ids.my_miesiac.text = miesiace[miesiac - 1]
        self.ids.my_rok.text = str(rok)
        self.ids.my_dzien_tygodnia.text = dni_tygodnia[dzien_tygodnia - 1]
        self.ids.my_dzien_roku.text = str(dzien_roku)
        self.ids.my_dluga_rachuba.text = str(current_long_count).replace(", ", ".").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

class Test_4App(App):
    def build(self):
       return Calendar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
        Test_4App().run()
```

And Kivy part:

```
<Calendar>
    orientation: "vertical"
    TextInput:
        id: my_date
        font_size: 30
        multiline: False
        text: "Insert date in DD.MM.YYYY format and press ENTER"
        on_text_validate: root.calculation()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Label:
                id: my_dzien
                font_size: 30
                text: "default"
            Label:
                id: my_miesiac
                font_size: 30
                text: "default"
            Label:
                id: my_rok
                font_size: 30
                text: "default"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Label:
                id: my_dzien_tygodnia
                font_size: 30
                text: "default"
            Label:
                id: my_dzien_roku
                font_size: 30
                text: "default"
            Label:
                id: my_dluga_rachuba
                font_size: 30
                text: "default"
```

Fast explanation to some post comments out here: this is my first ever python program, and I started learning it few days ago. I just like to jump on deep waters instead of wasting time.

As for my final question: How do I make my textinput widget (or whatever this is) centered?
And to make it more precise: I want the very text I write centered inside the textinput widged, not widget centered inside bigger structure.